# marshalling a log file into an xml file - Java

Tags: java, xml

I have a log file with the following output:

```
2226:org.powertac.common.TariffSpecification::6::new::1::CONSUMPTION
2231:org.powertac.common.Rate::7::new
2231:org.powertac.common.Rate::7::withValue::-0.5
2232:org.powertac.common.Rate::7::setTariffId::6
2232:org.powertac.common.TariffSpecification::6::addRate::7
2233:org.powertac.common.Tariff::6::new::6
2234:org.powertac.common.TariffSpecification::8::new::1::INTERRUPTIBLE_CONSUMPTION
2234:org.powertac.common.Rate::9::new
2234:org.powertac.common.Rate::9::withValue::-0.5
2235:org.powertac.common.Rate::9::setTariffId::8
```

After I parse the file, have the following pattern:

```
<id>:<full_classname>::<order_of_execution>::<new_or_method>::<params>
```

The parser works nicely, and does what I expect. Now, my goal is to marshalling that same instruction into a `XML` file. I'm totally unfamiliar with this kind of task.
So, the `XML` would have to contain both `new` objects and `methods` call.
I know using the `Reflection` API I would use the `<full_classname>` to create an object of that class:

```
Class<?> cl = Class.forName( className );
```

How could I generate such `XML` file from that `Class` object? Do I have to have a data-structure or a way to take all the methods and fields of the object and write them to the xml file? I know the Reflection API has such methods, but I would need a more general / sample idea of how could I accomplish my task.
I started to write down this method, but I'm not sure how would it work:

```
// would send in the object to be marshalled. 
public void toXML(Object obj){
        try {
            JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Object.class);
            Marshaller m  = context.createMarshaller();
            m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Here is a sample of the parsed file:

```
171269 org.powertac.common.Order 171417 new 4
171270 org.powertac.common.Order 171418 new 4
171271 org.powertac.common.Order 171419 new 4
```

The `parse` method looks like:

```
public void parse() throws ClassNotFoundException{
    try{
        //
        // assure file exists before parsing
        //
        FileReader fr = new FileReader( this.filename );
        BufferedReader textReader = new BufferedReader( fr );
        String line;
        File input = new File("test.xml");
        //Integer id = 1;
        while(( line = textReader.readLine()) != null ){
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([^:]+):([^:]+)::([\\d]+)::([^:]+)::(.+)");
            Matcher m = p.matcher( line );
            if (m.find()) {
              int id = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));
              String className = m.group(2);
              int orderOfExecution = Integer.valueOf( m.group( 3 ));
              String methodNameOrNew = m.group(4);
              String[] arguments = m.group(5).split("::");
              //
              // there is the need to create a new object
              //
              if( methodNameOrNew.compareTo( "new" ) == 0 ){
                  //
                  // inner class
                  //
                  if( className.contains("$") == true){
                      continue;

                  }
                  else if( className.contains("genco")){
                      continue;
                  }
                  System.out.println("Loading class: " + className);
                  LogEntry le = new LogEntry(id, className, orderOfExecution, methodNameOrNew, arguments.toString());

                  Serializer ser = new Persister();
                  ser.write(le, input);
                  id++;
                  System.out.printf("%s %s %d %s %d\n", id, className, orderOfExecution, methodNameOrNew, arguments.length);
              }

        }

        }
        textReader.close();
    }
    catch( IOException ex ){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch( ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public void write() throws Exception{
        File file = new File("test.xml");
        Serializer ser = new Persister();
        for(LogEntry entry : entries){
            ser.write(entry, file);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Look at: JAX-B, XMLBeans, even Jackson+XML.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a first try using [Simple XML](http://simple.sourceforge.net/) library:

```
@Default()
public class LogEntry
{
    private int id;
    private Object classInstance;
    private String orderOfExecution;
    private String newOrMethod;
    private String params;

    // throws 'Exception' only for testing
    public LogEntry(int id, String className, String orderOfExecution, String newOrMethod, String params) throws Exception
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.classInstance = Class.forName(className).newInstance();
        this.orderOfExecution = orderOfExecution;
        this.newOrMethod = newOrMethod;
        this.params = params;
    }


    // getter / setter 
}
```

And how do make XML out of the class `LogEntry`:

```
// Here is an example of an entry
LogEntry le = new LogEntry(3, "com.example.MyClass", "abc", "def", "ghi");

Serializer ser = new Persister();
ser.write(le, new File("test.xml"));
```

Simple XML is very easy to use, see here for [tutorials](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php) and [examples](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/examples/examples.php).
You can custumize the whole XML with the Annotations in the LogEntry Class, however you can also let `@Default()` do everything for you :-)

Comment: Ollo, your answer is great, but how am I going to create an object from a flat file, as I described in the problem?

Comment: What does the parser return, can you give some more information about it? Does it return a String for each logline? File --> Parser --parses--> LogEntry --make XML--> XML File, this is how the whole thing should work.

Comment: For an object of your Class(name) you can use: `Class.forName(className).newInstance()` or call the constructor through reflection

Comment: Could you help me with that?
I've added this to my code: `Object obj = Class.forName( className ).newInstance();`; What's next in order to use `Simple XML` or `XStream`?

Comment: If you uses something like the the class i posted from above, its very simple: do nothing :-) @Default will mark all fields of your class for you. Can you post your new code?

Comment: Yes, but how am I going to give the arguments to the class?

Comment: updated my post (a bit) too. Is it possible to change the returntype of your parser? So you can return a List of Entries?

Comment: Only to be shure i'm on the right way: do you want to serialize alle informations of your log or only the a object of your "full_classname"?

Comment: I want to serialize all the information from my log file ... I also tried your approach, and I got an error:
`Loading class: org.powertac.common.Tariff
java.lang.InstantiationException: org.powertac.common.Tariff`

Comment: Do Tariff an the others have an constructor without arguments or only with? `newInstace()` requires an empty constructor.

Comment: if you parse your logfile, do you have all its arguments available (from log or somewhere else)? btw. you can invoke a constructor too: `Class.forName(.. classname ...).getConstructor(.. types of arguments ..).newInstance(.. arguments ..)`

Comment: yes ... from the code you have `arguments[]` is the array of arguments used either by the constructor, or by the method being called: `Object[] arguments = m.group(5).split("::");`

Comment: Ollo, how can I write more than one `LogEntry` to the `xml` file?

Comment: hmm ... for getting the proper constructor you need the types (= their classes) of each argument. But this looks difficult for entries like this: `[1, INTERRUPTIBLE_CONSUMPTION]` (int, String/enum?)

Comment: Ollo, they are just strings on the flat ... see the file sample I've posted ?

Comment: An the arguments of constructor for org.powertac.common.... classes are Strings to? (yes, see it)

Comment: Ollo, it's more complex than that ... for example, `2233:org.powertac.common.Tariff::6::new::6` : the class `org.powertac.common.Tariff` takes an object of the type `Rate`, but it is only represented as `"6"` in the file.

Comment: Ok, and where you get an object of `Rate`? Create an new one or use an existing one?

Comment: but how do I know which arguments does the constructor take? I will give you an example:
`223082 org.powertac.common.Order 172411 new 4
Constructor:
  public org.powertac.common.Order(org.powertac.common.Broker,org.powertac.common.Timeslot,double,java.lang.Double)`

Comment: Ollo, can I send you an email?

Comment: Opposite direction: you tell what arguments you have and reflection gives you the proper constructor (or an exception if there's none). But i guess its better we do the other things first - seems the part with the classes is very complex. I'll post a reworked parse Method, and the LogEntry class, lets see what we can do here.

Answer (score 1):

**LogEntry:**

```
@Default()
public class LogEntry
{
    private int id;
    private Object classInstance;
    private int orderOfExecution;
    private String newOrMethod;
    private List<Object> args;

    public LogEntry(int id, Object classInstance, int orderOfExecution, String newOrMethod, List<Object> args)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.classInstance = classInstance;
        this.orderOfExecution = orderOfExecution;
        this.newOrMethod = newOrMethod;
        this.args = args;
    }

    public LogEntry() { }


    // getter / setter / toString / ... here

}
```

**parse Method:**

```
// Here all entries are saved
private List<LogEntry> entries = new ArrayList<>();

// ...

public void parse() throws Exception
{
    // Don't compile this in a loop!
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([^:]+):([^:]+)::([\\d]+)::([^:]+)::(.+)");

    FileReader fr = new FileReader(this.filename);
    BufferedReader textReader = new BufferedReader(fr);
    String line;

    while( (line = textReader.readLine()) != null )
    {
        Matcher m = p.matcher(line);

        if( m.find() )
        {
            LogEntry entry = new LogEntry();
            entry.setId(Integer.valueOf(m.group(1)));

            String className = m.group(2);

            entry.setOrderOfExecution(Integer.valueOf(m.group(3)));

            String methodNameOrNew = m.group(4);
            entry.setNewOrMethod(methodNameOrNew); // required in LogEntry?

            Object[] arguments = m.group(5).split("::");
            entry.setArgs(Arrays.asList(arguments));


            if( methodNameOrNew.equals("new") )
            {
                if( className.contains("$") == true  || className.contains("genco") )
                    continue;

                createInstance(className, arguments);
            }
            else
            {
                callMethod(className, methodNameOrNew, arguments);
            }

            // XXX: for testing - set the instance 'not null'
            entry.setClassInstance("only for testing");
            entries.add(entry);
        }
    }
    textReader.close();
}
```

---

**Edit:**

Lets say your parse()-Method, the List etc are in the Class `Example`:

```
@Root
public class Example
{
    private File filename = new File("test.txt");
    @ElementList
    private List<LogEntry> entries = new ArrayList<>();

    // ...


    // Only 'entries' is annotated as entry -> only it will get serialized
    public void storeToXml(File f) throws Exception
    {
        Serializer ser = new Persister();
        ser.write(this, f);
    }

    public void parse() throws Exception
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Note: For this example i've added `entry.setClassInstance("only for testing");` above `entries.add(...)`, else the instance is `null`.

---

**Edit #2:** Helper methods for parse()

```
private Object createInstance(String className, Object args[])
{
    // TODO
    return null;
}


private void callMethod(String className, String methodName, Object args[])
{
    // TODO
}
```

Comment: there is an error when I try to write that to a xml file ... I updated my question and I added my `writeXML()` method.

Comment: I use **simple xml** instead of jaxb here - if you use jaxb here, you need to set proper anotations. (See my edit, storeToXml() added)

Comment: The one with creating new instances?

Comment: Yes.... I thought about a recursive algorithm, which does the same as a compile parser (tooooo much work)

Comment: Here my first question: does __new__ mean "new instance of this class" and the rest "call method of this class"?

Comment: `2234:org.powertac.common.Rate::9::new` means new instance of this class.

`2234:org.powertac.common.Rate::9::withValue::-0.5` means call method of this class

Comment: then there is the "new" keyword, it means to create a new object ... when there isn't then it's a method call.

Comment: See edit above, now we have to find a way for the new 2 methods.